# Creating a document from a string in Gecko

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, firefox-addon, gecko

I have a string such as 
`<html><body><div id="message">Hello World!</div></body></html>` 
and I would like to get the content of the #message element without parsing the HTML myself.

I thought maybe I could create a document object from a string in Gecko (this is for a Firefox add on) but I don't see any simple way.

I noticed that there is a [createDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMImplementation.createDocument) method, but that doesn't take a string. I'd have to strip the `<html>` portion from the text, and then again I'm starting to assume stuff.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT: This seems to work for me:**

```
doc = document.implementation.createDocument( "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html", null );
doc.firstChild.innerHTML = '<html><body><div id="message">Hello World!</div></body></html>';
node = doc.getElementById( "message" ); 
alert( node.innerHTML );
```

Comment: You should add a new answer with your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you get the string from? If it's XML, you could get away with using `DOMParser`.

Otherwise, you have to create an HTML document - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_HTML_From_Chrome.

The fact that just using `createDocument` works seems suspicious, because people used more complicated solutions all this time.

Comment: I get it from a remote source via an xhr.

Comment: I will try the domparser method too, just curious if it works and is simpler. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, but who controls what format that remote source returns data in?

Answer (score 3):

Don't like answering my own question, but this seems to have worked for me:

```
doc = document.implementation.createDocument( "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html", null );
doc.firstChild.innerHTML = '<html><body><div id="message">Hello World!</div></body></html>';
node = doc.getElementById( "message" ); 
alert( node.innerHTML );
```

Comment: Don't forget to declare variables.

Comment: They are declared in a single, comma separated line at the beginning of the method. We use jslint.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always that syntax?  If so, why not use a regex?

Comment: It may or may not be always that syntax.